log4j2 not printing any log messages with debug severity
I am running a spark program scala where I am stuck with this particular scenerio where my log messages with debug severity are not being printed.
Here is my code snippet
object TestLogging{
  @transient lazy val log = LogManager.getLogger(getClass().getName())
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    log.debug("printing debug")
    log.info("printing info")
    log.warn("printing warn")
    log.debug("printing debug 2")
    log.error("printing error")
    log.fatal("printing fatal")
}

Here is my log4j2.properties file
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = console
 
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_ERR
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n%ex
appender.console.threshold = DEBUG

Here is the ouput from console
24/12/05 15:56:13 INFO TestLogging$: printing info
24/12/05 15:56:13 WARN TestLogging$: printing warn
24/12/05 15:56:13 ERROR TestLogging$: printing error
24/12/05 15:56:13 FATAL TestLogging$: printing fatal

Any idea what I am doing wrong.
PS: log4j-core and log4j-api version 2.22.1 are in the pom.xml and this Object is a part of a spark/scala project. Currently I am not doing any spark related stuff but summitting the code with sparkOperator on a kubernetes cluster

I tried to run that piece of code and couldn't reproduce the issue you are reporting. Could be that this code is not enough to reproduce your problem? You said that you are running a spark app but no spark in the example provided. There is a Log4j Scala API. It's just an API, which means you also need to set log4j-core as a dependency. To have the logger available, you have to mix the trait Logging from org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging

hey mate, I just removed the sparkSession object as I am not doing anything related to spark except for  using SparkOperator to run the code on a kubernetes cluster.  Its part of a larger maven project and I am using log4j2 and have both log4j-core and log4j-api  version 2.22.1 included in my pom

With that code, I can't reproduce the problem you have. Could be that you have some config in your kubernetes cluster that is overriding the log config file you have? Could be an issue on how your cluster is setup? Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible example?

I think its probably the log4j2.properties file not getting added to classpath and hence the issue. But having said that log messages for other severities are being printed which is what is baffling me. If I make any  other changes to log4j2.properties file such as changing log severity by changing rootLogger.level to warn, the changes are reflected in logs

Could be possible that kubernetes or the way you are getting the logs filter out the debug message?

Setting spark.driver.extrajavaoptions and spark.driver.extrajavaoptions to -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=<path to my log4j2.properties file> -D-Dlog4j2.debug worked for me. The steps on the page https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting are quite helpful.
